# How to print this number pattern using loops in JAVA?

Tags: java, loops

How do I print this pattern modifying my original code below:

I am a beginner in java and not able to create the pattern listed below.

Pattern:

```
1
1 ,1
1 ,2 ,1
1 ,3 ,3 ,1
1 , 4 , 6 , 4 , 1
1 , 5 , 1 0 , 1 0 , 5 , 1
```

My Code:

```java
public class Q2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int count = 5;
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print(i);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

My Output:

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
```

Comment: It's called Pascal's Triangle.  Read up on how it works: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle

Comment: If you Google it,you will find answer more quickly,you can see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19918994/pascals-triangle-format

Comment: http://www.javawithus.com/programs/pascal-triangle

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pascal's triangle 2d array - formatting printed output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935254/pascals-triangle-2d-array-formatting-printed-output)

Answer (score 1):

I wish I could comment but I don't have enough reputation.

You need to add something to Yimin's answer to calculate the factorial, for example.

```
static int factorial(int n){    
    if (n == 0)    
        return 1;    
    else    
        return(n * factorial(n-1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `i choose j` for each term. This is by formula:

```
i!/(j!*(i-j)!)
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int count = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print(factorial(i) / (factorial(j) * factorial(i - j)));
            System.out.print(' ');
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: The code isn't working, it's giving me the factorial error

Comment: You need to include something with `factorial()`, or roll your own.